# Installing Homebrew on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6

Tags: bash, homebrew, macos-sierra

I've been trying to install homebrew on my Mac using the script on the homepage `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`.

I was getting [this invalid developer directory error](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/xcode-select-error-invalid-developer-directory-library-developer-commandlinetools-failed-during-usr-bin-sudo-usr-bin-xcode-select-switch-library-developer-commandlinetools/693). I tried uninstalling Xcode following [this guidance](https://macpaw.com/how-to/uninstall-xcode-on-macos) and then running `xcode-select --install` which seemed to work. My Xcode was originally installed in `~/Applications` not `/Applications` for some reason.

Now the script is failing at the same point, but seemingly because it can't download the command line tools.

```
Error downloading Command Line Tools (macOS Sierra version 10.12) for 
Xcode: not found
Done.

Error downloading updates.
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/rm -f 
/tmp/.com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand.in-progress
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select --switch 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory 
'/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools'
Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select --switch 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

I don't really understand what the script is doing but shouldn't it identify that the CLT are already installed?

I'm not sure where to go from there, any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Anyone have thoughts on this?

Comment: Eventually I fixed this by removing my xcode installation and then installing just the xcode command line tools `xcode-select --install` and then resetting the path to my xcode command line tools `xcode-select --reset Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`